# @Transactional Annotation + for a data insertion in a loop

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am using **Spring 3, JPA + Hibernate** for a `CMS` application. In that application I have a service class method which is annotated with `@Transactional` Annotation with `rollBack` property. Inside that method I am inserting data (ie entity classes) to a table using a loop. For each `iteration` of the loop entity classes has to be saved to the database. But it is not happening. The commit only happens when the execution of the loop has completed and exits from the method. Then it commits and saves all at once. But I need to read data once it gets inserted into the database before committing in this case. I tried with the `ISOLATION LEVEL` to read uncommitted but it didn't supported since I am using the default `JPADialect`. Also tried to add the **hibernate** implementation of `jpaDialect` but still it didn't worked. Please help with a workaround for this problem. One more thing, is there any way using propagation required method.

Comment: You seem to have realised what your problem is. You've just got your transaction boundaries in the wrong place. Once you fix that you should find that it works as expected.

Comment: You should be able to read uncommited data inside the same transaction without commit or changing isolation level. As far as I know this is the most common behaviour..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the transactional annoation on the the method with loop.

In the loop call a separate method to perform the save, make that method transactional

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NimChimpsky, But i have a class level Transactional Annotation, even if i removed the Transactional annoation from the method with loop and give it to the another method in the same class. It wont work, since the class level annotation is already present. Is there any way that i can specify the Transactional annotation at class level to ignore some methods defined in that class, ie not for consideration of Transactions Management.

Comment: just remove class level annoation and add it to each method you want

Comment: i tried with that, but when i run the application it throws an TransactionRequiedException saying 'no transaction is in progress'. I have created two methods, in service class in one method i wrote some business logics and in the second method i wrote codes to create entity classes and refers DAO class to save those entity class. For the first method i didnt give any annotation, but for the second method i annotated with Transactional annoation with propagation Requires New property. The execution starts from the first method.

Comment: @Krishna the transactionactional method has to be in different class to the calling method, according to Tomasz below.

Comment: @NimChimpsky..Thanks for your reply. I do understand the problem. But i think Spring should support methods without Transactions inside a Service class, like their in the Test environment nottransactional.

Comment: @Krishna they do but I think the problem arises when you call a transactional method from a non-transaction method within the same class. You can have non-transactional methods in yr service class, they just can't call another method in same class that is transactional.

Comment: @krishna you can always override the class level transaction with the method level.

Answer (score 16):

You are right, this is what `I` stands for in [acid](/questions/tagged/acid). Because the transactions are working in isolation, other transactions cannot see them before they are committed. But playing with isolation levels is a bad practice. I would rather advice you to run each and every iteration in a separate transaction with start and commit inside.

This is a bit tricky in Spring, but here is an example:

```
public void batch() {
    for(...) {
        insert(...)
    }
}

//necessarily in a different class!
@Transactional
public void insert() {

}
```

Note that `batch()` is **not** annotated with `@Transactional` and `insert()` has to be in a different class (Spring service). Too long to comment, but that's life. If you don't like it, you can use `TransactionTemplate` manually.

Comment: I would like to use the TransactionTemplate, to solve this problem, but i am using Declarative Transaction approach for the other service classes. Is it a bad behavior to mixing both Programmatic Transactions using TransactionTemplate with Declarative Transactions.

Comment: Will this really work? 
"In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behavior so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. " - spring reference manual

Answer (score 1):

You either need to go with programmatic transactions (Spring's `TransactionTemplate` or `PlatformTransactionManager` are the classes to look at, see [Spring Doc for programmatic transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#transaction-programmatic), or you can call another transactional method from within your loop where the transaction is marked with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`, meaning each call of that method is executed in its own transaction, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#tx-propagation). I think that the second approach requires you to define the REQUIRES_NEW method on a different Spring bean because of the AOP-Proxy. You can also omit the REQUIRES_NEW if the loop is not executed within a transaction.