# Making transactional calls to the DB when using UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a User class marked as entity which also implements UserDetails. I want to be able to grab some properties of a certain user, and based on their values, to return specific roles in the `getAuthorities` method. Many of those properties are however lazy-loaded and require a  Hibernate transaction.

I tried anything from making the user class `@Transactional` to making the `UserDetailsService` and `RememberMeService` which I use `@Transactional`. None of those works!

All of my other DAO and Service classes mapped as transactional work (and they are just simple classes - no other annotations besides a @Transactional on top)

UPDATE: This is the overriden getUserDetails in class User

```
@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        GrantedAuthority auth = new GrantedAuthority() {

            @Override
            public String getAuthority() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "ROLE_USER";
            }
        };

        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        if (options.size() > 0) {
            for (Option o : options) {
                result.add(createAuthority(Option.getStringType(o.type)));
            }
        }

        result.add(auth);

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Not clear what the question is ? Lazy load your authorites then, or change to eager fetching ...

Comment: @Transactional does not work. At least in that case

Comment: what is the error message ? show some code. Are you persisting each users grantedauthorities - just treat it like any other property.

Comment: The exception is quite well known - there is no session bound to thread :)

Comment: lol, yeah i am familar with that. Are you calling the same session twice before flushing/commiting ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721004/transactional-annotation-for-a-data-insertion-in-a-loop/9721104#9721104

Comment: shwo the transactional method on serice class that is nto working as well

Comment: *All of my other DAO and Service classes mapped as transactional work* mapping both services and DAOs seems like a bad idea. Transactions should be started in either the service or the dao layer (preferably the service layer), but not in both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserDetails` is not a Spring bean and thus is Spring is not going to look for `@Transactional` on it.

I would need to see a stack trace but what I'm assuming is that getAuthorities() is being called by another `UserDetailsService` method directly, i.e., not going through the transactional proxy.

Inject the `PlatformTransactionManager` into your `UserDetailsService` and use a `TransactionTemplate` in `getAuthorities()` to wrap your DB accessing code in a transaction.